# Meaning of (a = b) == 0

Tags: javascript

Just read on Javascript book by David Flanagan this case:

```
(a = b) == 0
```

But I can't see the use of this. Could be like this?

```
var b = 0;
var a = b;
if (a == 0) ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah your presumption is true.

Comment: You could give us the context of the issue - what is Flanagan talking about here? Is he showing how you can assign things whilst comparing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The assignment returns the assigned value.

It just assigns `b` to `a`. If `b` (and consequently `a`) is 0, the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

It's evaluated in this order:

```
(a = b) == 0
-------
^ assign the value of b to a
------------
Check if the value of a equals 0
```

Pretty much it's the same with:

```
a = b;
if (a == 0) {
   // do something
}
```

It's just a shorter version. Don't forget to declare the variables, otherwise they will be appended to the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is the short form. Means:

1. Assign b to a
2. Then compare the value.

Answer (score 0):

`(a = b)` assigns `b` to `a` and is furthermore an *expression* with the new value of `a`.

So `(a = b) == 0` is an *expression* that assigns `b` to `a` and is evaluates its relational equality to 0.

In C and C++ you'll often see it written as `if (!(a = b))`. Some folk find such a form obfuscating as it's a stone's-throw away from the considerably different `if(!(a == b))`.

Comment: if a is falsy. is double equals not a triple one